# Group by amount and display first and last position

Tags: javascript

Hello I have these data:

```
[
 {amount:1, position:1},
 {amount:1, position:2}, 
 {amount:1, position:3}, 
 {amount:2, position:4}, 
 {amount:2, position:5}
]
```

and I want to convert them to

```
[{amount: 1, range: "1-3"}, {amount: 2, range: "4-5"}]
```

Is there a library that can do this?

**EDIT**

My first attempt with underscore. I group them by amount and then I map them. But is this the best way?

```
data = _.groupBy(data, function (item) {
    return item.amount;
})

data = _.map(data, function (item, index) {
    return {
        amount: index,
        range: _.first(item).position + "-" + _.last(item).position
    }
})
```

Comment: I don't know about an existing library but its pretty simple code to write. Should the first range be 1-3 though?

Comment: why amount2 is inside amount1 ?? shouldn't it be `[{amount:1, range:"1-4"}, {amount:2, range:"4-5"}]` ??

Comment: sorry I meant  1-3. fixing it

Comment: There is nothing difficult. Just some time is required to solve this simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you use http://underscorejs.org or https://lodash.com, neither of them has a function to directly solve your problem, but you can combine a few existing functions in a creative way to do it :) Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn functional programming =] <3

```js
var y = [{amount:1, position:1},{amount:1, position:2}, {amount:1, position:3}, {amount:2, position:4}, {amount:2, position:5}]
var amounts = []

y.map(function(obj){
  obj = y.reduce(function(a,i,ii){
    if (ii === 1){
      if (a.amount === obj.amount){
        a.position = 1
        a.set = true
      }else{
        a.amount = obj.amount
        a.set = false
      }
      return a
    }

    if (i.amount === a.amount && !a.set){
      a.set = true
      a.position = i.position
      return a
    }

    if (a.amount === i.amount)
      a.range = i.position
  
    return a


  })
  return {amount:obj.amount,range:obj.position+'-'+obj.range}
})
.filter(function(obj){
  if (!amounts[obj.amount]){
    amounts[obj.amount] = true
    return true
  }
  return false
})
```